# Check if reference to cell is Valid

Tags: excel, vba

I am importing a csv file which has cell references to a worksheet. The cell reference can be wrong, because the user once made an error typing the cell reference (for example: instead of "AM1" the user wrote "AMQ") or something different went wrong.

The problem is, that I have more than 1000 cell references which can change dynamically and there can be any error imaginable, as the user can write anything into it.

I am trying to write a function which checks if the reference is valide, but I can't find a solution for checking if the cell reference exists in excel.

For example, I have this code but it always gives a run time error back, because the Range(rng).Row function doesn't work if rng is not a valide input. But how do I work around it?

This as exptected always works:

```
Sub Test()
    rng = "A1"
    flag = rangeExists(rng)
    debug.print flag
End Sub
```

This doesn't work:

```
Sub Test()
    rng = "AQ"
    flag = rangeExists(rng)
    debug.print flag
End Sub
```

The function:

```
Function rangeExists(ByVal rng As String) As Boolean
    
    Dim row_int As Integer
    
    row_int = Range(rng).Row
    On Error Resume Next
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        rangeExists = False
    Else
        rangeExists = True
    End If

    On Error GoTo -1

End Function
```

I am trying to find a solution with the Error Handling in VBA, but I am not able to do so. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What is the value RangeExists() is returning? It seems like it's not returning any useful data. Let me rephrase, what is the function supposedly identifying? And what are you trying to identify? Blank cells, formula error, where a relative reference is missing?

Comment: @Brett I am trying to copy values and strings from a CSV file to a worksheet. The function is supposed to identify if the cell reference in the CSV file is a teachnical correct cell reference like A1 or AM58, but not AQ or A\JA. If it is a correct reference, then this function should return a boolean true and if the return value is true, then the a another function (which is processing the data) should not skip the entry. If it is false, then the function should skip this row with that cell reference and note this wrong entry.

Comment: @braX How can I tell it, if it is a valid range? I would need return a true if it is a valid range and a false if it isn't. I am trying to find a function or a way, in which I am checking if the cell reference is valid in an loop.

Comment: I see now. Never used this method, but I like the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will simply return `True` if it's a valid range, and `False` if it's not.

```
Function IsRangeValid(ByVal rng As String) As Boolean
    Dim r As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range(rng)
    On Error Goto 0
    IsRangeValid = (Not r Is Nothing) ' parenthesis optional
End Function
```